# @Inject , @AutoWired, @Resource & @ManagedProperty : which one should I use ,where and when?

Tags: spring, rest, jsf-2, annotations, managed-bean

I'm using Hibernate, Spring & JSF for an application.
I'm actually evolving the application with a Restfull WebService with Jersey(JAX-RS). For that need i annotated my class with @Component. Inside this class, i need to call a service to grap some stuffs from the database.

```
@Component
@Path("/Graphic")
public class GraphicService {

    //@Autowired //@Inject
    //ParticipantBo participantBo;

    or       

    //@ManagedProperty("#{participantBo}")
    //private ParticipantBo participantBo;
```

I meet some annotations in tutorials that i don't know/understand well the meaning.
So i'd like to make a check-up to see if my configuration for the whole application is ok or if i could clean up some stuffs.

Most of the time, i'm using @*ManagedProperty* Annotation to include a dependency (a ServiceBO which one call then a Dao) inside my class annotated with @ManagedBean.

```
@ManagedBean(name="participantController")
@ViewScoped
public class AddParticipantBean  implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6952203235934881190L;

        @ManagedProperty(value="#{participantBo}")
        ParticipantBo participantBo;
}
```

I have an applicationContext.xml file where i declare all my classes this way :

```
 <!-- Participant Data Access Object -->
   <bean id="participantDao" class="X.X.X.dao.participant.ParticipantDaoImpl" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
   </bean>    

   <!-- Participant Business Object -->
   <bean id="participantBo" class="X.X.X.bo.participant.ParticipantBoImpl" >
        <property name="participantDao" ref="participantDao" />
   </bean>
```

Is my configuration well done ? Could i configure the application differently ? , maybe without xml declaration ? using @*Inject* or @*AutoWired* maybe ? But what are the use cases for them ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefere to use the standards that Java EE provides. And also I prefere to annotate the setters instead the property directly. With this way is more easy to start doing unit testing (and mocking these objects). Check also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25449931/1228193)

For example your class GraphicService will be like this:

```
@Component
@Path("/Graphic")
public class GraphicService {

   ParticipantBo participantBo;

   @Resource
   public void setParticipantBo(ParticipantBo participantBo){
        this.participantBo = participantBo;
   }
```

More info about [@Resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html)

Hope it helps.